# Perform SIP Call from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, sip, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-voip

I'm trying to learn to develop SIP client for Windows Phone 8.1 (following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) example).

The example mentions to call:

```
Windows.Phone.Networking.Voip.VoipCallCoordinator.RequestNewOutgoingCall()
```

to perform outgoing call. However, from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662966.aspx), RequestNewOutgoingCall is to  "Notifies the system of a new outgoing call." Not to connect to the actual SIP server.

Anyone knows how to connect to the desired SIP server?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not provide ready solutions for SIP call. You must use one of the existing third-party components. Existing SIP frameworks have rather poor version for Widows Phone:

- PJSIP - library does not use background agent that makes it impossible to use it in an existing application.
- Doubango - code rather poorly supported, so the latest versions (during last 6 months) contain errors, which not allow using this framework. Not implemented some of popular components - for example: Acoustic Echo Canceller.

We use custom Doubango library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Alexei. I managed to create a simple app that perform outgoing call with PJSIP in windows 8 (thanks to your suggestion in previous answer). It worked fine and I'm planning to dive in further into PJSIP to create full-fledged app. But, now that you mention PJSIP doesn't use background agent, how does this will affect the SIP app? You mention that it is impossible to use in existing application but the simple app I created can work. Where do I miss?

Comment: In an app for Windows Phone (not Windows 8) without background agent you can not: talk in a closed app, receive incoming calls, use the earpiece.

Comment: Hi Alexei. Could you please let me know how pjsip should use the background agents?

Comment: I tried to integrate in PJSIP into chatterbox, but so far no positive results achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You must use SIP native library, eg PJSIP

Comment: This answer is too short to be useful.  You should at least include a link to the library, or comment why this would solve the problem: the OP asks why a particular method connects to the actual SIP server; how is this related to non-native libraries?